# Twig and Silex, generating dynamic forms

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I'm trying to generate a form on Twig using two for loops to generate the names and every form element. For some reason I'm getting some expression problem, but really can't find the issue. Maybe somebody can help.

```
{% for l in 1..line %}
<div class="row">
    {% for r in 1..row %}
    {% set form_name = "name_l_"~l~"_r_"~r~"_a" %}

    <div class="col-md-{{ cols }}">
      {{ form_label(form.~form_name, "Line: "~ l ~" total") }}
      {{ form_widget(form.~form_name, { attr: { 'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Twig_Error_Syntax in ExpressionParser.php line 382:
Expected name or number

Comment: You can't append dynamic variables like that and retrieve from an object in Twig.  Have you tried `form[form_name]` instead?

Comment: yep, worked that way. Thanks :)

Comment: okay cool I posted that as the answer then so others can know that is how to fix the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot append dynamic variables like that to access members of the object.  You need to change:

```
form.~form_name
```

to this:

```
form[form_name]
```

which will achieve what you are looking for.